# What JIRA API URL can be used to get details in dashboard?? (like: "To Do" "In Progress")

Tags: api, jira, jira-rest-api

view the following immage for the dashboard
[image: dashbord]

Comment: I don't understand your questiion, what dashboard details you need? Possible issue statuses? Board columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way I used, create a filter with a JQL (Jira Query Language) that returns the list you want (like in your case, based on status).  Save your filter with a name you will easily find.

Then in your dashboard, add the "Filter Results" gadget.  It comes with Jira, no need to setup a plugin for this.  Then configure the gadget to show the results of the filter you just created.

Another way would be to setup a Scrum board, with 1 column per status.  Your issues will automatically be shown in the right column.  You can even drag-drop them between columns to change the status.

Comment: If it solves your question, please approve the answer :-)